# Extract string between two parameters within xml file using batch preferrably

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I've been struggling with extracting data between two strings in an xml file.
I need to extract the data between two tags.

The two tags are:

```
<ns3:UTF8String id="ChassisNo">

</ns3:UTF8String>
```

I have tried code that i have found that extracts string between two tags, but the tags are usually simpler, like the one below.
Also the tags i want to extract data between contains quotation marks.

```
<tag> </tag>
```

I have tried using the following code, but i am unable to make it work for my example.

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\a067935\Desktop\Wheel alignment"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\test.xml"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /i /L /c:"<ns3:UTF8String id="ChassisNo">" "%filename1%"') DO SET "name=%%a"
SET "name=%name:*<ns3:UTF8String id="ChassisNo">=%"
FOR /f "delims=<" %%a IN ("%name%") DO set "name=%%a"
ECHO "%name%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Example xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:WriteRequest xmlns="ng:eie:common:header" xmlns:ns2="ng:eie:datapoint:writerequest" xmlns:ns3="ng:eie:common:datatypes" dataPointID="Request">
    <ns2:Header>
        <Timestamp>2017-07-05 14:27:18.979</Timestamp>
        <UniqueID>f558c39c-cb19-439a-97fb-2c2dfd4a0f2e</UniqueID>
    </ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Data>
        <ns3:Struct id="Request">
            <ns3:Integer id="Version">1</ns3:Integer>
            <ns3:UTF8String id="Operator">a262236</ns3:UTF8String>
            <ns3:Array id="Identifiers">
                <ns3:Struct id="Identifier0">
                    <ns3:Struct id="UnitIdType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="Type">KD</ns3:UTF8String>
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="Id">01KD000001</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                    <ns3:Struct id="DeliveryOrderType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="ProductType">KD</ns3:UTF8String>
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="DeliveryOrderId">0000160751</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                    <ns3:Struct id="ExecutionOrderType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="Id">0000160751_KD</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                    <ns3:Struct id="InstructionType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="Id">0000160751_KD</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                    <ns3:Struct id="TraceabilityType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="Id">KD-01KD000001</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                    <ns3:Struct id="ChassisIdType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="ChassisType">M</ns3:UTF8String>
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="ChassisNo">943524</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                    <ns3:Struct id="VINType">
                        <ns3:UTF8String id="Id">YVgfhffj66943524</ns3:UTF8String>
                    </ns3:Struct>
                </ns3:Struct>
            </ns3:Array>
            <ns3:Array id="Operations">
                <ns3:Struct id="Operation000">
                    <ns3:Integer id="Sequence">0</ns3:Integer>
                    <ns3:Integer id="OperationCode">1</ns3:Integer>
                    <ns3:UTF8String id="OperationProgram">1</ns3:UTF8String>
                    <ns3:Integer id="BatchSize">1</ns3:Integer>
                    <ns3:Array id="Parameters">
                        <ns3:Struct id="1">
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="1">F1,D1,D2</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="2">R</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="18">Y</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="13">590</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="14">445</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="17">3</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="3">D1</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="12">375</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="11">-1295</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="21">1190</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="103">0,2</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="101">0</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="105">1</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="23">1,5</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="102">0</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="107">0,5</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="22">1</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="104">2,2</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="20">850</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="113">22,5</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="401">3600</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="112">385-65</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="402">0</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="412">315-80</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="115">Y</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="413">22,5</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="114">Set</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="403">0,2</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="514">Measured</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="501">1370</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="503">0,2</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="512">315-80</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="415">Y</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="513">22,5</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="506">0</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="414">Measured</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="502">0</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="507">2</ns3:UTF8String>
                            <ns3:UTF8String id="515">Y</ns3:UTF8String>
                        </ns3:Struct>
                    </ns3:Array>
                </ns3:Struct>
            </ns3:Array>
        </ns3:Struct>
    </ns2:Data>
</ns2:WriteRequest>
```

Comment: You should be made aware that scripting languages like Powershell, Vbscript and Jscript all have native capability to read and write XML files. Yes you can brute force it sometimes with batch files but as the complexity grows it is easier to use a language that has native capability to read and write XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q45583503.txt"

FOR /f "tokens=1-7delims=<=>" %%a IN (
 'findstr /R "ns3:UTF8String.id=.ChassisNo." "%filename1%" '
) DO ECHO chassisno=%%d
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q45583503.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Using the restricted-regular-expression facility of `findstr` with the `delims` capacity of `for/f`.